# Redirection operator is limiting columns

Tags: bash, ubuntu-10.04, dpkg

I am running the following command to list the packages installed on a server.

```
$> dpkg -l
```

This is fine but when I do this

```
$> dpkg -l > list_of_packages_installed
```

I only get 106 columns of data and the rest is cut off. So all the rows are there but not all the data column-wise. There must be something simple I am missing here?

Comment: I am connected by SSH. I have increased the size of my local shell to the maximum (although I didn't really think that was the issue). I have checked $COLUMNS and it was 237.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it on my Lucid. What terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: I checked Help-> about and got 'GNOME Terminal 2.30.2' so I assume the GNOME terminal emulator. I tried dpkg - l > test on my local ubuntu 10.04 machine and got the same loss of data issue.

Comment: Okay. What if you pipe file through less?

Comment: Say, $ cat list_of_pachages_installed | less -S

Comment: tell us how you know you are only getting 106 columns of data AND do you mean columns as in $COLUMNS (i.e. 106 characters wide) OR 106 words in columns (like a spreadsheet). What do you get if you run `awk  '{print $NF ":" length($0) ":" $0}' list_of_packages_installed` ? Good luck.

Comment: No idea why, but i made it work as expected with `COLUMNS=$COLUMNS dpkg -l >k`

Comment: @PabloCastellazzi: that works for me as well.

Comment: @shellter: I meant 106 characters wide for the longest lines. 106 is the number I get for the longest lines when I run your script on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable COLUMN is indeed responsible for this.  The manpage of dpkg(8) contains under the section "ENVIRONMENT":

> ```
>    COLUMNS
>          Sets  the number of columns dpkg should use when display-
>          ing formatted text. Currently only used by -l.
> ```

if COLUMNS is set in your environment then dpkg will use it.  You can check with
this command:

```
env | grep ^COLUMNS=
```

if that command outputs something like

```
COLUMNS=80
```

then you know that this variable is set in your environment.
Note that this command:

```
echo $COLUMNS
```

does not tell you if it is an environment or a shell variable.  COLUMNS can be set as a shell variable without being exported to the environment.  With this command:

```
COLUMNS=$COLUMNS dpkg -l > k
```

you explicitely put the variable in the environment of dpkg.
If it was not in your environment then it will be for this command only.
Also note that the behaviour of dpkg in this respect is different between
ubuntu and debian and also depends on the version.  There have been a few
bug reports on this topic.  The dpkg in squeeze for example will set the
column width so that all package names and version can be displayed in full
if COLUMNS is not set in the environment and the output is not a tty.

Regards