# Bash - stdout text gets truncated when redirected to a file

Tags: python, linux, bash

When working in Bash on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), text output is truncated at times. I'll explain what I mean.

Suppose, you issue the "dpkg -l" command. dpkg then writes to its standard output a long list of installed packages, the lines of text are not truncated and everything's OK. Now, you try to dump the output of the command to a file - "dpkg -l > dump". When looking at the file contents, you'll see that some of the lines (those that are quite long) have been truncated. What logic is responsible for this behavior?

Also, I conducted a small experiment. When working with the Python interpreter interactively, I type the following:

```
from os import popen2

child_input, child_output = popen2("dpkg -l", "t")          # running the command "dpkg -l" in a subprocess so that I can then obtain what it writes to its stdout via a pipe

dump_file = open("dump", 'w')                               # create a file to write to

for string in child_output:                                 
    dump_file.write(string)                                 # writing the child's output to the dump file, one line at a time

dump_file.close()
```

When typed interactively, the code works fine - no truncation occurs. Once I place that code in a script and run it, some of the long lines get truncated. Why does this happen?

Comment: I guess because `dpkg -l` is basically `dpkg-query` which products output based on the environment variable `COLUMNS`... Just running it normally with a resized shell windows truncates ...

Comment: unrelated: you could dump the output of a subprocess to a file using `subprocess` module: `subprocess.check_call("dpkg -l".split(), stdout=open("dump","wb"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using COLUMNS variable before executing commands in bash;

feel the difference:

COLUMNS=80 dpkg -l 
and
COLUMNS=300 dpkg -l

Comment: Thanks, stimur and all those who took their time to answer the question. This behavior is indeed influenced by the COLUMNS var. By the way, there is a similar topic about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648718/redirection-operator-is-limiting-columns I should have looked around before starting this one.